# Android: Service como puedo ejecutar un servicio en segundo plano aun destruyendo la applicacion

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-service

Tengo el siguiente codigo para enviar una notificacion luego de varios millisegundos desde un service todo funciona perfecto aun cuando salgo de la aplicacion pero quisiera que los millisegundo sigan contandose aun cuando destruyo la app. Alguna idea de que me falta implementar para lograr esto?

class MyServicio : Service() {

```
companion object{
    val ID_CHANNEL:String = "com.example.channelnotification";
    val NAME_CHANNEL:String = "Android_Channel";
    private val Notification_ID = 0;
}
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    CreateChannelNotification()

}

private fun CreateChannelNotification() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val channel = NotificationChannel(ID_CHANNEL, NAME_CHANNEL,importance).apply{
            description = "Esta es la notifiacion"
        }
        val notificationManager:NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)


    }
}
private fun ShowNotification(){
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, ID_CHANNEL)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti)
        .setContentText("Notificado")
        .setContentTitle("Recivido")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
        notify(Notification_ID, builder.build())
    }
}


val myDate = "2020/11/29 18:10:45"
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
val date: Date = sdf.parse(myDate)
val millis = date.time
override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {

   return null;
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postAtTime({
        Log.e(TAG,"Service is runing");
        ShowNotification()
    }, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 3000)
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes llamar a [startForeground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)), los servicios que se encuentren corriendo en Foreground no se detendrán aunque se cierre la aplicación.

Para esto tendrías que crear una notificación que mantenga vivo el servicio (esto podría implicar crear un nuevo NotificationChannel).

```
private fun getNotification(): Notification {
    return  NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ID_CHANNEL_FOREGROUND).apply{
        setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti)
        setContentText("Foreground")
        setContentTitle("Corriendo")
        priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    }.build()
}


override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    startForeground(100,getNotification())
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postAtTime({
        Log.e(TAG,"Service is runing");
        ShowNotification()
        stopForeground(true)
    }, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 3000)
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Aunque esta podría no ser la mejor opción, si lo que buscas es ejecutar una acción en un momento determinado, quizá lo mejor sea usar [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)